# download excel file from web using vba

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-9

i have the following code to download an specific file from the web. the webpage has the name of the file and if you click on it you get the "Do you want to open or save ....... from ......?Open/Save/Cancel.
this is what i have so far:

```
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Navigate "http://customerservice.ciena.com/BidRegister/Queue.aspx?REGIONID=3"
Set fe1 = html.getElementById("ctl00_P1_rdgFileList_ctl00_ctl00_btnGetFile")
fe1.click
```

at this point i get the pop up message i was telling you about above. How can i continue my code to either avoid this pop up and directly save the file in a given location? is there a line of code that saves the file directly?

Answer (score 2):

From what I recall by using the Internet Explorer object you can't bypass its safety prompts.

I get round this at work by using post/get requests via a serverhttp object, getting the file as a responsebody and then use ADODB object to save the body directly to predetermined location.

Here is an example for a GET request which should download a file directly from the URL:

```
set objhttp = new MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
URL = "http://www.princexml.com/samples/catalog/PrinceCatalogue.pdf"
objhttp.Open "GET", URL, False
objhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objhttp.send
If objhttp.Status = 200 Then
Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write objhttp.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "filepath and filename.pdf", 2
    oStream.Close
End If
```

To make this work for a POST request you need a bit more info. To try and find the info you will need to use the F12 Developer tool on internet explorer:

- Have InternetExplorer open on the page you're downloading from
- press F12 to open the developer tool
- Click on "Network"
- Click on the "play" button ("Enable network traffic capturing")
- now download the file and you should see the POST that requested the file pop up in the Network summaries.
- Double click on that POST line in the F12 tool and click on "Request body", whatever is in there is the goldmine, the thing that was sent to the URL to request the file. If you can interpret that and deploy it in your code then you've cracked it.

the last thing to do would be to change two lines in the code above:

```
 objhttp.Open "POST", URL, False
 objhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 objhttp.send (This is where you put the data string i.e. the REQUEST BODY)
```

Sorry I can't specify any more, there are tonnes of formats that a POST request body can have so without seeing an example of your system's I can't go any further.

Comment: "Put in your file request string here" is the name of the file or what?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more specific with example for this part because I couldn't seem to access the website via the URL you supplied to do a test. The "file request string" would be some key/value pairs that tell the server what you're after. I will try to find an example file download you can replicate on your site to get the gist of how it works.

Comment: Edited answer to show worked example for a GET request, if you can use your Network traffic monitor (For IE this is the F12 button) you will be able to see what the POST request string is when you download a file. Try to emulate that.

Comment: I see, but my url doesn't change when i click on the file. that's why i cannot track it. in your example you have "src=http://www.princexml.com/samples/catalog/PrinceCatalogue.pdf" really clear, i don't

Comment: If your URL doesn't change then I assume it must be a POST request you need to use. I will update my answer to locate how to find the strings required using POST requests. WIthout access to your specific site I can't really create a fully working code for your specific problem :(

Comment: thanks for all the help but i can't crack it unfortunately. couldn't find a reference to the file in that body

Comment: Ah that's a shame, all I can say is keep on trying - took me a bit of trial and error to crack this technique for the first time. Keep on monitoring the network traffic when you browse the site/ download from other sites. I use the technique all the time now to pull stuff from various systems at work and it's such a timesaver for me and others!